# C# Socket: is multiple sending less efficient than a single send?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am writing a high-throughput server serving thousands of connections. Suppose I have 400 bytes to send via a socket. Suppose I do it in two ways:

1. Call the Socket.Send() 40 times, each time sending 10 bytes.
2. Call the Socket.Send() once, sending 400 bytes.

Do these two ways make much difference in terms of speed, CPU load, etc?

Comment: You could measure it, but it shouldn't make a difference. `Send` is essentially "put these bytes in a buffer", the decision of when to send the bytes in the buffer out onto the network isn't controlled by that.

Comment: Calling any function that you don't have to call is inefficient

Comment: @user253751 technically true, but in many cases (certainly not all cases) the difference won't matter; as is always the case, and as Damien notes: if it *might* matter, then you need to measure it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Socket.NoDelay` is left at `false`, then it will very rarely make any difference - most of the time, you're just going to buffering locally - albeit with a bit more P/Invoke overhead than is absolutely necessary (due to lots of calls through the socket layer). Note that `Socket.NoDelay` should usually be set to `true` in anything where you care.

If `Socket.NoDelay` is `true`, then *if everything is working maximally*, then you *might* introduce additional packet fragmentation by using 40 sends of 10 bytes, which would be avoided when using one send of 400 bytes. However, in many cases, the various abstractions and layers in the OS/hardware stacks means that a lot of the 10 byte chunks will *probably* end up sharing packets. That's still a lot more packets than 1, in the optimal case, though.

Note also that this is always a trade-off: packet fragmentation will decrease *overall* throughput, but sending the first bytes sooner could reduce the perceived latency, if the other 390 bytes are going to take a measurable (but presumably small) amount of time to construct.

In most cases: this is unlikely to be a bottleneck. If you *can* avoid packet fragmentation without causing latency, that may be desirable. If it was me, I'd probably be more concerned with efficient buffer management to maximise scalability while avoiding pauses due to GC; tools like the new "pipelines" IO API can really help with that, and Kestrel can be used to host a TCP server based on "pipelines" in a lot **less** code than you would be using if you wrote your own socket listener - and it then deals with all the buffer management for you.

Comment: Thank you for your expert advice - helps me tremendously.